# Is it possible to increase MatLab's precision?

Tags: matlab, precision, trigonometry

I need to filter a rotation matrix and to do that I need to first convert it to rotation angles, then filter those and convert the answer back to a rotation matrix form. The problem is that chaining those two conversions together even without the filtering in between (i.e. `angl2rot(rot2angl(rotationMatrix))`) introduces a significant error due to the lack of precision in all the trig functions required to do the conversions.

Is there a way to increase the precision of MatLab in general? Or maybe in particular is it possible to make the trig functions (I use sin(), cos() and atan2()) more precise?

EDIT: There go the implementations of functions responsible for converting from rotation matrices to Euler angles and vice versa:

```
function [ rotationM ] = eul2rot( a, b, c )
%EUL2ROT This function converts euler rotation angles to a 3x3 rotaton
%matrix

    X = zeros(3,3,size(a,1));
    Y = zeros(3,3,size(a,1));
    Z = zeros(3,3,size(a,1));
    rotationM = zeros(3,3,size(a,1));

    for count = 1:size(a,1)

        X(:,:,count) = [1 0 0; ...
            0 cos(a(count)) -sin(a(count)); ...
            0 sin(a(count)) cos(a(count))];

        Y(:,:,count) = [cos(b(count)) 0 sin(b(count)); ...
            0 1 0; ...
            -sin(b(count)) 0 cos(b(count))];

        Z(:,:,count) = [cos(c(count)) -sin(c(count)) 0; ...
            sin(c(count)) cos(c(count)) 0; ...
            0 0 1];

        rotationM(:,:,count) = Y(:,:,count)*Z(:,:,count);
        rotationM(:,:,count) = X(:,:,count)*rotationM(:,:,count);

    end

end

function [ th ] = rot2eul( rot )
%ROT2EUL Converts a 3x3 rotation matrix into a vector of three euler angles
        th = [atan2(rot(3,2,:),rot(3,3,:)); ...
            atan2(-rot(3,1,:),sqrt(rot(3,2,:).^2+rot(3,3,:).^2)); ...
            atan2(rot(2,1,:),rot(1,1,:))];
end
```

They use the equations found [here](http://nghiaho.com/?page_id=846).

Comment: How do you quantify the lack/loss of precision?

Comment: A rotation matrix produced by `angl2rot(rot2angl(rotationMatrix))` is significantly different from the matrix `rotationMatrix` (the rotations they cause very by up to 5 degrees). The only thing `angl2rot` and `rot2angl` do is apply trigonometric functions and doing one matrix multiplication so I assume the discrepancy in the rotations comes from the little imprecisions in the trigonometric functions piling up.

Comment: Are these functions built in or from any matlab toolbox or are they handmade? I cannot find them on mathworks homepage.

Comment: 3D rotations? Are you sure your individual functions are correct - for the direction of rotation and order of rotations, etc - I just did a quick check and can convert back and forth without error (working in radians).

Answer (score 3):

The [site you link](http://nghiaho.com/?page_id=846) as your source defines rotation matrix R as:

```
R = Z*Y*X;
```

Where `X, Y, Z` are the three individual rotation matrices.

However, in your code you are doing this:

```
rotationM(:,:,count) = Y(:,:,count)*Z(:,:,count);
rotationM(:,:,count) = X(:,:,count)*rotationM(:,:,count);
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
R = X*Y*Z;
```

These two are not equivalent, because matrix multiplication is not commutative.  Changing the order is of multiplication is equivalent to changing the order in which the rotations are performed (and rotations in 3D are also not commutative), giving you a different result than you were expecting.

Answer (score 0):

The class HPF ([High Precision Floats](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36534-hpf-a-big-decimal-class)) by John D'Errico supports floats with an arbitrary number of decimals. You can also look at the function `vpa` of the Symbolic Math Toolbox.

Comment: These indeed seem to be methods to increase the precision beyond the limits of regular matlab, yet I would be surprised if this would help the asker.

Comment: And me too, but this time I preferred to answer the question directly rather than providing a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The functions that you mention like `sin` and `cos` are VERY basic matlab functions, and will not contain mistakes. The precision you get when using them is basically matlabs own precision (double precision, can easily have 14 decimals when you are working with the values I expect).

As such the suspect is clear: The homemade functions `angl2rot` and `rot2angl` are likely the problem. Either because they are bugged, or because they are used wrongly.

Without seeing the actual functions there is no way to tell more.

Comment: I added the code for the converting functions to the original question.