# Is it possible to circumvent Matlab epsilon?

Tags: matlab, rounding, numerical

I have two arrays of numbers which are almost identical. When I take their difference I get an array of half very small numbers (on the order of 1e-16), and half identically 0. I'm almost positive this is due to rounding issues; i.e. the difference between the two entries is less than epsilon.

That said I'd still like to show the difference between all the entries (even if they are extremely small). Is there some way to circumvent Matlab's epsilon tolerance? Perhaps using some clever scaling of the arrays?

EDIT : Here's an example of my issue. Array `a` is accurate to exactly 15 digits (being copied from a C file output), while array `b` comes from Matlab. Take one element of `a` which is exactly  `1.00002429399044`. Now subtract from this the corresponding entry in `b`, which *displays* as `1.00002429399044`. The difference between them is `2.22044604925031e-16` according to Matlab. This means that there must be more digits in the entry of `b` than are being displayed.

Consider the same scenario with the element of `a` being `1.00003105215213`. Now the difference between the this number and an element in `b` that *displays* as `1.00003105215213` is exactly `0`. I have a hard time beleiving that in this case the numbers stored are exactly the same -  that is if I could display more digits in Matlab I would expect see the difference between the two numbers.

Comment: you could use [Variable-precision arithmetic](http://mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html)

Comment: @m.s. That looks promising, although I'm using Matlab R2009b, and apparently vpa isn't avaliable

Comment: Did you try with `format long g`?

Comment: @HamtaroWarrior that only changes the display, not how things are calculated

Comment: My bad, thought it would change the type of the variable

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25184088/3676517

Comment: I am not sure if I am wrong, but AFAIK epsilon is the smallest difference between numbers that you can store in a double floating point. This means that your numbers **CAN NOT** have a smaller difference than epsilon, because machine precision limits it. Another thing is that the results of equation *f* would have differences smaller than epsilon, but once they are stored in memory, then its impossible that the differences are smaller.

Comment: @HH `vpa` is available in R2009b, but you need the Symbolic Toolbox

Comment: @LuisMendo Right you are, it was released for R2006. I do not have that toolbox though.

Comment: @Jommy another very good suggestion, but it won't work for me, and looking at some of the comments the issue is probably my older version of Matlab. The joys of working for a corporation.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I understand the issue, I was just wondering if there was some way to work around it. Seems like there's at least a couple, but unfortunately I lack the proper resources.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two [floating points numbers](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/floating-point-numbers.html) x and y in Matlab, and x-y evaluates to 0, that means x and y are in fact **equal**: they are internally represented by the same 0-1 string of length 64. The operation of subtraction did not lose information "due to rounding issues"; rather, you either didn't have information to begin with, or lost it prior to subtraction.

If you suspect that they x and y should not be equal, you have to look at what happened earlier, as they were calculated. It may   be possible to reorganize the computation knowing that the eventual goal is to compare x to y.

Simple example: if I want to compute y=sqrt(x^2+1) for some large x, that formula will do just fine as written. But if it turns out that my eventual goal is to compare the result to x, i.e., consider sqrt(x^2+1)-x, I'll proceed differently, using  the fact that sqrt(x^2+1)-x = 1/(sqrt(x^2+1)+x).

Comment: I don't think that's quite right. They are within epsilon of each other, so there is no floating point number between them, but they need not be exactly the same. I've added an example to my question to show what I mean.

Comment: Regarding your edit: yes there are various human-readable outputs you could get, but they all come from the same 64 bits that Matlab has stored ([IEEE 754 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)). You can see __exactly__ what Matlab has by using `fprintf('%bx', your_number)`: this outputs those 64 bits encoded for brevity as a 16-character hexadecimal string. If  `fprintf('%bx', x)` gives the same string as `fprintf('%bx', y)`, that's it -- x and y are identical.

Comment: @1999 Or just use `format hex` to get a general display of all bits, without needing to use `fprintf` for everything.